# How to stop javascript function execution for Certain event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call a function in javascript using `setInterval` function. Function will automatically execute  after 10 sec.  I want to stop and then restart the execution of function for certain html events eg. `onfocus`, `onfocusout`.

```
function myFunction(){
     setInterval( function (){
        $('.View').load('alert.php').fadeIn("slow");
     }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by: restart the execution of function ?

Comment: @Raptor  setInterval function again start its work,means it load again alert.php after 10 sec.

Comment: @user3422433 So you want the `setInterval` to execute just once ?

Comment: Quiet ambiguous question... need some elaboration...

Comment: @Raptor I want to stop setinterval function every time when event onfocus occur and then restart when event onfocusout occur.

Comment: use `clearInterval()` to stop the "timer", and reset it with `setInterval()`

Comment: @Raptor **clearInterval()** not working.

Comment: Define "not working".